# Extract ID from the JSON Response in Linux

Tags: linux, json, sed, grep, extract

Here is my json response from the server.This response i am saving in a variable named TESTDEMO.

```
{
"objects":[
   {
   "meta":{
          "type":"test-folder",
          "@href":"{HOST_URL}/TsetRESTServices/objects/test-folder/0F071CE4-790D11E3-AAC0-005056A5408D",
           "name":"demo"
          },
   "meta":{
          "type":"test-folder",
          "@href":"{HOST_URL}/TsetRESTServices/objects/test-folder/0F072CE4-190A11E3-AAC0-00AA56A5408K",
           "name":"folder "
          } 
    }]
 }
```

Want to extract the id `0F071CE4-790D11E3-AAC0-005056A5408D` of the folder `"name":"demo"`.
Need Help.

Comment: If "in Linux" means using command-line tools rather than a programming language, `jq` is a useful tool for JSON parsing.

Comment: @ChrisB: OK.Is it possible with any command like sed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

redirect your JSON to sed command and grep according to the name:demo.

```
echo $TESTDEMO | sed 's/{/\n{/g' | grep '"name":"demo"' | cut -d',' -f2 | cut -d'/' -f 7 | cut -d'}' -f 1 | cut -d '"' -f 1
```

Hope this will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
awk  -F"[/\"]" '/"name":"demo"/ {print $5}' RS="}" <<< "$variable"
0F071CE4-790D11E3-AAC0-005056A5408D
```

Comment: json data i am saving in a variable not in the file. syntax is not applied to the variable.

Comment: use `awk  -F"[/\"]" '/"name":"demo"/ {print $5}' RS="}" <<< "$TESTDEMO"`

Comment: @ruifeng Beat my by 5 sec :)  Updated example

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/"type":"test-folder"/,/"name":"demo"/ {s/[[:blank:]]*"@href":"{HOST_URL}//;s/",$//p}' <<< "$TESTDEMO"
```

take the block `type` to `name` and print line havin @href and finished by ', after removing them